# How to solve this nonstandard trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I want to solve this equation $$\sin(\sin(\sin(\sin x)))=\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos x))),$$ but I don't know how to solve.

Comment: "Numerically" is probably the only way forward here.

Answer (score 6):

No real solutions.
[image]
Do you want complex solutions?

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: Assume he does because then the question is pointless.